# how can I make a column unsortable when using the dojo toolkit's grid?

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I've got a grid (dojox.grid v1.2) that I don't want to be sortable. How can I disable that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it:

http://dojotoolkit.org/forum/dojox-dojox/dojox-grid-support/disable-sorting-specific-column-0

To save linking:

In your onload, or postrender add code like this:

`dojo.byId('myGridId').canSort = function(col){
    if(Math.abs(col) == 3) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};`

(Note, the columns seem to be indexed from 1 in this setting.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your grid programatically you can do the following:

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({ 
               ..., 
               canSort: function(col) { return col != 3; }
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute `canSort : false` to hide or disable sort button in `Dojo DataGrid` code:

```
var newGrid = new DataGrid({

        id : 'newGrid',

        canSort:false,

        store : this.resultStore,

        structure : this.resultGridLayout,

        autoHeight:true
});
```

Regards,

Satish M Hiremath

Answer (score 0):

I think right solution is

```
dijit.byId('yourgridid').attr('canSort', function(col){

    if(Math.abs(col) == 3) {
      return false;
    } else {
       return true;
    }

});
```